# Probability that a trigonometric random variable is non-zero

Tags: probability, measure-theory, functions, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider $n$ iid random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$, such that

$$X_i = \cos \theta_i,$$

where $\theta_i$ is chosen uniformly at random from $0$ to $2 \pi$.

Now, consider the random variable

$$X = \underset{\theta_i, ~i \in [n]}{\min} ~|\cos \theta_i|.$$

I am trying to find the probability that $X$ is greater than $0$. I have the intuition that this is overwhelmingly close to $1$ and that the set of points for which $X$ is $0$ is a measure zero set. Is the intuition correct?

Comment: Are we able to get an explicit form for the cdf of $X$ or the $X_i$'s? cos not being invertible on $[0, 2\pi]$ makes solving for the CDFs by substitution more difficult. If we have these we can utilize that the probability of X being greater than 0 is 1 minus the probability that X is less than or equal to 0 (which is the cdf @ 0).

Comment: But isn't $\theta>0$ by the formulation?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\pr}{\operatorname{Pr}}$Notice $X\ge0$. So, $\Pr(X>0)=1-\Pr(X=0)$.

Now, $X=0$ if and only if there exists $1\le j\le n$ with $\cos\theta_j=0$. $\cos^{-1}\{0\}$ is countable and has null measure: because each $\theta_\bullet$ is uniformly distributed, it follows $\pr(\cos\theta_\bullet=0)=0$.

It then follows that $\pr(X=0)=\pr\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n(\cos\theta_j=0)\right)\le\sum_{j=1}^n\pr(\cos\theta_j=0)=0$ and that $\pr(X>0)=1$.

This does not require independence, or even that the $\theta_{\bullet}$ are identically uniform. We only need that each $\theta_\bullet$ has absolutely continuous distribution.